# How to resolve the selendroid server startup error?

Tags: selendroid

I have followed the steps from this link http://selendroid.io/setup.html to launch the selendroid server.But I am getting the following error message,when I give this following command.

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.13.0-with-dependencies.jar -app selendroid-test-app-0.13.0.apk
```

I am getting the following error message,it got struck with middle of the installation.

```
 supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '160' '240' '320' '480'
<--
Jan 23, 2015 2:35:10 PM io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver getSupportedDevices
INFO: Error occurred when building supported device info: null
Jan 23, 2015 3:27:51 PM io.selendroid.standalone.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver getSupportedDevices
INFO: Error occurred when building supported device info: null
```

In the local host http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status ,I am getting the following details.I am not getting the full details that has been portrayed in the document.

```
 {"status":0,"value":{"supportedApps":[{"appId":"io.selendroid.androiddriver:0.13.0","mainActivity":"io.selendroid.androiddriver.WebViewActivity","basePackage":"io.selendroid.androiddriver"}],"os":{"arch":"amd64","name":"Linux","version":"3.13.0-32-generic"},"build":{"browserName":"selendroid","version":"0.13.0"},"supportedDevices":[]}}
```

Comment: Have you created any virtual android device?

Comment: @HelpingHands now it got resolved,Thanks.

Comment: Great. How it resolved?

Comment: @HelpingHands, I am new to this ,so i blindly started installing,after that only i studied that material,I plugged the hardware device.Then ,i got the required details.

Comment: okay.its nice that issue solved.

Comment: @selvi if you could add the solution to your question it will be helpful for other readers who may face the problem in future..

Comment: I have created a new android avd  and then i have started it using command "android avd"  and then android emulator get started.